# How do I see which DLL is running in a given thread on a computer without Visual Studio installed?

Tags: c++, windows

There is a problem coming from a third-party DLL in our application, and it happens on a client's computer, which doesn't have Visual Studio installed.

Is there a way to 'break' the application and see which DLL is executing (for a given thread) at that moment? Some lighter-weight tool, perhaps?

Comment: So can you just unrecommended the close given my specific edit? You can always post an answer.

Comment: See my edit, do you agree with it? If that is your intended question now, then it's answerable, and I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Process Explorer. Double click on a process, then open Threads tab, and double click on a thread.

[image]